# Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms on windows mobile

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

Is the `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms` namespace available on Windows Mobile ? Or is it strictly for Windows CE only ?

I am trying to create an application that runs on 2 operating systems: Windows CE and Windows Mobile.

Visual Studio lets me develop using this package. But when I run my application on a full-blown windows system (with a full blown .net version), this namespace appears unavailable. That's not really a problem.

But my fear is, that this namespace will also be unavailable when I run my application on a Windows Mobile operating system. Currently I only have a Windows CE device available for testing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Windows Phone is completely another OS, so I don't think you can run Windows CE apps there.

Comment: *correction - "windows mobile", not "windows phone", I corrected the title of my question.

Comment: Then it should work out of the box, as Windows Mobile is built upon Windows CE (same kernel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms can be used on Windows Mobile too. But the layout may differ a bit as on Windows Mobile al Forms run maximized (except you use native API to change there Window State).

Keep an eye on the form size and remember that Windows Mobile Forms show a menu bar at bottom and the taskbar at top. The taskbar replaces the Window Caption and is smaller than a normal caption.

The actual layout also depends on Mobile Version, Windows Embedded Handheld 6.6 is different to previous versions. See also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/04/19/windows-mobile-6-5-changed-screen-geometry/